# Need good design pattern for caching database query result set

Tags: java, sql, jakarta-ee

I'm part of a team architecting a Java web application wherein users will search for results in a relational database and then view them in tabular fashion in a browser.  Users will then also have the option to subsequently view the same result set (or a subset of those results) in a separate browser window, using for example a charting tool.  In other words, we need to give the user the ability to visualize the same result set records later (up to a limit of 24 hours).

Since searches on the system will be resource-intensive and just out of good common sense, we would like a clean way to cache each result set so that it can be pulled later from memory (RAM or disk).  **We are looking for a good approach to doing this caching**, we believe others have done this before, and we prefer to use a best-practice or framework rather than building such a thing from scratch.  The server will have plenty of RAM but since there could be hundreds of people using the system, we may need an approach that stores to RAM first but then can also cache to hard disk if RAM is getting full.

I believe it makes most sense to persist as Java objects but I'm open to better advice.  We would like a vendor-neutral approach, so that if the database team chooses to switch vendors later we aren't stuck with a proprietary solution. Thanks.

Comment: ahhh text wall. please at least format to prevent bloody eyes

Comment: you'd get better results if you format your question and make it as simple and to the point as possible..

Comment: Please edit your post to make it more readable...

Comment: hold the results in beans in an arraylist. Then just ask for the arraylist instead of the resultset. So query the database once a day, and then hold the result in arraylists and when the user asks for it just grab the arraylist. That's similair to what youtube does and why it takes a couple hours to see an update on your user page. Each refresh does not query the db.

Comment: i believe the term you wanted to use is `framework`, not `design pattern`

Comment: OMG his question is entirely clear: how to implement query result caching.  Reading 3 paragraphs is not going to kill you people.

Comment: This isn't source code, it's a problem description.  Too often people are chastised here for not providing enough context, so I provided context. Feel free to tell me exactly which part of this description is not both necessary and useful to explaining such a problem.

Comment: It is possible that the solution to this problem is not a framework, but a pattern of source code, therefore I intentionally did not use the term "framework".

Answer (score 4):

I think what you might be looking for is Terracotta Ehcache.  This does everything you mentioned and more. It is a free product that can be used to cache things in memory, overflow to disk, specify max cache sizes by either MB or # of items, and expire based on last access time or entry time.

Comment: EhCache is pretty sweet. My experience has been 'just works.'

Answer (score 1):

I've seen http://www.jboss.org/infinispan/ used to do exactly that.  It can cache to memory, disk and or database.  I wouldn't say I love it (the configuration is not super easy and documentation is somewhat lacking) but it most certainly works and is actively maintained.

Answer (score 1):

Being vendor neutral is all about writing an abstraction layer that is native to your application, then plugging in the cache service you would like to use behind this layer, while keeping your layer that exposes these operations to your main code the same.

There are plenty of ways to cache. Look into using various NoSql solutions.

- [Redis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redis)
- [Memcached](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memcached)

Most of the time you will serialize your object and persist it to your cache layer.